# What can be the solution of lapindrome problem as stated below

Tags: python

I am new to competitive programming. I am solving the below problem and stuck

> Lapindrome is defined as a string which when split in the middle,
>   gives two halves having the same characters and same frequency of each
>   character. If there are odd number of characters in the string, we
>   ignore the middle character and check for lapindrome.   For example
>   gaga is a lapindrome, since the two halves ga and ga have the same
>   characters with same frequency. Also, abccab, rotor and xyzxy are a
>   few examples of lapindromes.   Note that abbaab is NOT a lapindrome.
>   The two halves contain the same characters but their frequencies do
>   not match. Your task is simple. Given a string, you need to tell if it
>   is a lapindrome.

Input:
First line of input contains a single integer T, the number of test cases.
Each test is a single line containing a string S composed of only lowercase English alphabet.

Output:
For each test case, output on a separate line: "YES" if the string is a lapindrome and "NO" if it is not.
Constraints:

```
1 ≤ T ≤ 100
2 ≤ |S| ≤ 1000, where |S| denotes the length of S
```

Example:
Input:

6
gaga
abcde
rotor
xyzxy
abbaab
ababc

Output:

YES
NO
YES
YES
NO
NO

Can you give me the solution of this problem with the logic behind the solution. (language=python)

Comment: "_Can you give me the solution_" ?  No.  Would I be ready to help if you'd written some code, but were unable to get it to work ?  Probably.

Comment: I got my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
a="abbaab"

def lapindrome(a):
    l = int(len(a)/2)
    return "YES" if sorted(a[:l]) == sorted(a[-l:]) else "NO"

print(lapindrome(a))
```

Comment: I think you're supposed to figure out the solution yourself though :D
Good luck with python - it's an amazing language!